# (Python) Use IMAP lib to download attachments and email details

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, email

This is my first approach to programming in Python, so I hope you will "destroy" my coding!

**Idea is to** use SSL connection to my mailbox and use IMAP to download attachments from emails with particular subject (all have same one for time being). Beside downloading files I want to display given subject and corresponding UID. Next step will be to save that data (specially subject and corresponding UIDS) in XML file and retrieve to download needed files without extra searches and fetching.

```
import imaplib
import email.header
import os
import sys

# Your IMAP Settings
host = 'imap.host.com'
user = 'email@adrs.com'
password = 'passwd'

# Connect to the server
print('Connecting to ' + host)
mailBox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host)

# Login to our account
mailBox.login(user, password)

boxList = mailBox.list()
# print(boxList)

mailBox.select()
searchQuery = '(SUBJECT "Desired Subject")'

result, data = mailBox.uid('search', None, searchQuery)
ids = data[0]
# list of uids
id_list = ids.split()

i = len(id_list)
for x in range(i):
    latest_email_uid = id_list[x]

    # fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID
    result, email_data = mailBox.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
    # I think I am fetching a bit too much here...

    raw_email = email_data[0][1]

    # converts byte literal to string removing b''
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

    # downloading attachments
    for part in email_message.walk():
        # this part comes from the snipped I don't understand yet... 
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue
        fileName = part.get_filename()

        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join('C:/DownloadPath/', fileName)
            if not os.path.isfile(filePath) :
                fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()

    subject = str(email_message).split("Subject: ", 1)[1].split("\nTo:", 1)[0]
    print('Downloaded "{file}" from email titled "{subject}" with UID {uid}.'.format(file=fileName, subject=subject, uid=latest_email_uid.decode('utf-8')))

mailBox.close()
mailBox.logout()
```

Thanks in advance!